# Oracle sql case over a computed column

Tags: sql, oracle

I Want to write in oracle sql, case over a computed column. The query is as follow.

```
Select trunc (Cost*100/Amt) as 'Computed_LTV', 
Case
When Request_Term <19 THEN '60'

When Request_Term <=24THEN'-18'

When Computed_LTV <70.805 THEN '-20'

ELSE '-60'

END AS "Var_1"

FROM LOAN_APP
```

Answer (score 2):

It is used only once, so I'd suggest you use the same formula:

```
SELECT TRUNC (Cost * 100 / Amt) AS Computed_LTV,
       CASE
          WHEN Request_Term <  19                THEN '60'
          WHEN Request_Term <= 24                THEN '-18'
          WHEN TRUNC (Cost * 100 / Amt) < 70.805 THEN '-20'       --> here
          ELSE '-60'
       END AS Var_1
  FROM LOAN_APP
```

If you insist on using a computed column, you'll have to use a CTE or an inline view, but that's probably *a little bit too much* in this simple case.

Also, get rid of double quotes in Oracle. They cause nothing but problems.

---

In order to sum several computed columns, do exactly that: sum them up. For example:

```
select trunc(cost * 100 / amt) as var1,
       round(amount * price)   as var2,
       --
       -- sum them using the "+" operator
       (trunc(cost * 100 / amt) + round(amount * price)) as result
from ...
```

Or, if you computed them in a CTE, you'd then

```
with data as
  (select trunc(cost * 100 / amt) as var1,
          round(amount * price)   as var2
   from ...
  )
-- now sum them up
select var1 + var2 as result
from data
```

Comment: Just to know that i have to sum up the new column values with writing similar cases. In the about case We have created new column as 'Var_1' similarly i Want 'var_2', 'var_3' how can i sum up this new computed columns.

Comment: I added some more code into the answer; have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-use a column alias in the `SELECT`.  But starting in Oracle 12C, you can use a lateral join to define it in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT x.Computed_LTV, 
       (Case When Request_Term < 19 THEN '60'
             When Request_Term <= 24 THEN'-18'
             When Computed_LTV < 70.805 THEN '-20'
             ELSE '-60'
        END) AS Var_1
FROM LOAN_APP la CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT TRUNC(Cost*100/Amt) as Computed_LTV FROM DUAL) x;
```

Note:  Do not escape identifiers -- using either single quotes or double quotes.  That just clutters queries, making them harder to write and to read.

Comment: Last thing to know can We write multiple cases for the same computed column name. For instance,  SELECT TRUNC (Cost * 100 / Amt) AS Computed_LTV,
       CASE
          WHEN Request_Term <  19                THEN '60'
          WHEN Request_Term <= 24                THEN '-18'
          WHEN TRUNC (Cost * 100 / Amt) < 70.805 THEN '-20'       --> here
          ELSE '-60'    When consdesc ='Salaried' and Age >'35' Then '73' else '-27' When consdesc! ='salaried ' and Age <56 else '-56' 
       END AS Var_1
  FROM LOAN_APP